# Does Visual Studio 2012 Save Files That Fool Dropbox?

Tags: file, visual-studio-2012, dropbox

I am using VS2012 for a new Windows Store app. I have two machines, a Win8 PC and a MacBook Pro, both using the same DropBox account to keep work files synced. Here is the problem. I currently work solely on the PC, using VS2012. Yet I continually get a popup dialog message that the file I have been editing and testing with has been modified by another program, do I want to reload it?

I decline to reload it, and then go to a separate text editing program to compare the two files.

Here is what I find.The file labeled "home.js" still contains the original contents from when I started my editing session. The file labeled "home (Dell1405's conflicted copy 2013-02-08).js" agrees with my latest updates. So it seems that DropBox has tried to sync the newer copy of the file, but is lead to believe that file is from another source, and so marks it a a conflicted copy.

So the "new" file that VS alerted me about is actually the latest copy that was saved when I ran my project in debug mode, and it agrees with the code shown in the VS edit window.

So my question is: While debugging, is VS saving my code file in some temporary area different than the disk location where I see it? And is this what is confusing DropBox (and me)? If so, how can I fix it?

I guess I could shut down DropBox on my PC before starting to work, but then I'd have to resort to sneaker-net to move edited images from my Mac to PC.

Comment: Check the clocks on both computers. Are the times/dates correct on both?

Comment: Also, what edition of Visual Studio are you using - Express, Pro, Ultimate? Something else?